# Compile SPEC06 dealII on OSX, missing cstddef

Tags: c++, macos

I am compiling the SPEC06 dealII using clang on Mac OSX. I am using the following portability settings.

447.dealII=default=default=default:
CXXPORTABILITY= -fpermissive -include cstddef -include cstdlib -include cstring

However, it gives me an error while building, says cannot find cstddef. Anyone have an idea to get rid of that? I have tried several options but failed. Thanks in advance.

T

Comment: can you post a link to the documentation? those include options look like garbage to me

Comment: Which error (exact)? What is your compiler? what is version of compiler (OSX, Xcode)? Dealll has the defect of not including cstddef before using ptrdiff_t, it is author error - https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=44416#c7. Just correct source and include cstddef in it (add `#include <cstddef>` in first lines of benchmark source).

Answer (score 0):

I have met the similar problems, I solve it with the full path. Maybe you can try the full path of these head files too.